# What kind of paper should I use for bottle labels?

Tags: bottles, bottling, labels

Do I need to use heavier paper (ie, 30 lb) for labels?  Would regular printer paper work just as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend getting label paper with the adhesive already on the back, like [this stuff](http://store.brewhut.com/whitelabelpaper-18sheetsof85x11.aspx). Otherwise it's going to depend on your glue, though based on the thickness of the label paper you'll probably want at least 28 lb. If you'll be printing on an inkjet, I'd also recommend getting some of [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WWFPYM) to waterproof them.

Answer (score 2):

How are you sticking the labels to the bottle?

I've used regular cheap printer paper, applied using some milk (skimmed is fine).  Simply paint the back of the label with milk, apply to bottle, allow to dry.

It does not smell (honestly!) and washes off easily.

Comment: I need to try this!